# Implement check constraint for varchar (7) to enforce YYYY-MM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, check-constraints, regular-expression

I am considering the following with regards to implementing a check constraint on a column I am calling `year_month`. My objective is to have a check constraint to enforce `YYYY-MM`.

- My intention is to create the column with data type: `varchar(7)`
  example value that would be saved from my front end: `2017-08`

Would I then add a regular expression to enforce only numbers, dashes and max 7 in my check constraint setup? Or could I  add some sort of regular expression to check for this pattern more exactly?

Comment: Oh, and you’d be better off storing it as a `date` datatype using the first day of the month. Makes it easier to do comparisons & other operations

Comment: @BernardV, date will also require only 4 bytes of storage rather than 9 bytes (7-byte varchar value plus 2-byte field offset). You could also add a check constraint like `DATEPART(day, DateColumn) = 1` to constrain the value to the first of the month.

Comment: I disagree with the suggestions to hack your values to squeeze them into a date field. Generally best to not "tell a lie" in your database structure. Some languages such as Java have a data-type to represent a year-month, such as the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class in Java. SQL lacks such a type. So the next best option is indeed to store a String of seven characters in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of `YYYY-MM`. This format happens to be chronological when sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 3):

You could try concatenating a valid 'day' on to the YYYY-MM values and use a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression and the [ISDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql) function.

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.TEST
        )
    DROP TABLE dbo.TEST
go
CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID INTEGER
    ,YYYY_MM_CHAR CHAR(7) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT chk_YYYY_MM_CHAR CHECK (
        CASE 
            WHEN ISDATE(YYYY_MM_CHAR + '-01') = 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END = 1
        )
    );

INSERT INTO TEST (ID,YYYY_MM_CHAR) VALUES(1,'2014-01')
INSERT INTO TEST (ID,YYYY_MM_CHAR) VALUES(1,'2014-13')

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 9
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_YYYY_MM_CHAR". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.Test", column 'YYYY_MM_CHAR'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: This will work provided they aren't using `SET DATEFORMAT YMD` (which may not be very likely but is still worth mentioning regardless, I think). Another thing is, this will probably not prevent them from using a different delimiter, so values like `2014.01` or `2014/01` will likely be permitted. (No idea if that's an issue but it's worth mentioning as well IMHO.)